# How can I host Laravel project which is also running a python script

Tags: python-3.x, hosting, laravel-7

I'd like to know how can I host a Laravel project which is running a python script to get recommendations for one of its module. Obviously, locally I'm running it with XAMPP server but how do I host it? Which service should I use?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understood, you have a python script that does something and share the result with your laravel project?

i would recommend to create a flask app that have an API that accept the required info form laravel, and respond the required information, this way you can host laravel on apache server and the python script on Gunicorn

another solution would be to run the script via shell_exec, refert to this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php (python path/yourscriptname.py), and get the output result, this way you need to have python installed on the server, and the website will be hosted on apache.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. I will check the the first solution that you recommend. And will get back to you If it worked.

Comment: i already have the same implementation i have both cases in my laravel project, and both works, but it depends on your requirement you choose which method!

Comment: that's good, I have successfully deployed my API using Flash server, now I am just trying on Laravel, hopefully, it will work too.

Comment: Simply host the laravel project on apache, and the python flask project on gunicorn and run each server on a different port